# Setting up jdbc in Maven project

Tags: java, mysql, maven, jdbc, odbc

I have been working on a maven project solely for junit tests.  I have created a class to access and do simple queries against the db.  Not sure if i am installing the `mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar` correctly or not, here is a snippet:

```
/home/rick/examples/java/junit/lib/ mvn install:install-file \
    -Dfile=mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar \
    -DgroupId=com.oracle \
    -DartifactId=oracle \
    -Dversion=10.2.0.2.0 \
    -Dpackaging=jar \
    -DgeneratePom=true
```

Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: What is your *question*? *Describe* your problems/issues?

Comment: This is incorrect. You are installing JDBC driver for MYSQL into your local repository as the Oracle JDBC driver..... Which database are you using? The MYSQL driver is already available from Maven Central (See Will's response below). License restrictions prevent the Oracle JDBC jar from being similarily hosted..

Answer (score 6):

You can put it directly in your pom and not have to install it locally.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.22</version>
</dependency>
```

See [search.maven.com](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cmysql-connector)